# How do I make a 8 meters(W) X 4 meters (H) banner on Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, billboard

I'm trying to make a 8 meters(W) X 4 meters (H) banner on Photoshop, but I can't figure out the right resolution for it, and for the other stuff like "Colour Mode," etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question has been answered many times before,

1. Depending on how far away the banner will be seen from you adjust resolution accordingly. So if the banner will be seen up close about 2-3 feet, 150 dpi is enough. If its further away, about 6-8 feet, you'll be ok with 75 dpi and if its even further its ok at 25 dpi.
2. Colour mode is always CMYKY for print.